# Is this a superfluous ansible tag?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

While many may like ansible, to me it seems with it rather conflating and somewhat redundant concepts like `tags`, `roles`, `inventory/hosts files`, `hostgroups`, `playbooks`, `tasks` `"when" conditionals` there is quite some challange to determine what eventually will be executed. The issue at core of this question is [`tags`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html).

My understanding is that if I have a playbook in which there is a role that contains a list of tags, those are added (inherited) by all of the contained tasks

Example:

```
[----./playbook.yml----]

---
- hosts: all
  roles: 
  - {role: role01, tags: ['tag01', 'tag02']} 
  - {role: role02, tags: ['tag01', 'tag03']}
```

would mean that all tasks found in `./roles/role01/tasks/main.yml` would implicitly be tagged with `tag01` and `tag02`. Confirming this would be part of an answer to this question

Likewise all tasks in `./roles/role02/tasks/main.yml` are hence tagged `tag01` and `tag03`, right?

Now the issue here is that looking at the file `./roles/role01/tasks/main.yml` I see this content

```
[----./roles/role01/tasks/main.yml----]
---
- block:
  - name: "upgrade all packages"
    yum:
      name: '*'
      state: latest
  tags:
    - tag01
```

Considering that the role is **exclusively only ever refered** from the line of `./playbook.yml` shown above, I fail to see how it makes any sense to have the `tag01` since it should be implicitly tagged given the line:

`- {role: role01, tags: ['tag01', 'tag02']}`

Also it completely disturbs me that another ansible concept `block`, had to be used here?

Aspects to the question:

1. Was tagging in the role's `main.yml` superflous ?
2. Why the use of a block (considering there is only one task anyway)?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;Dr**: yes indeed in the case explained in the question (the implicit tagging at the level of the ansible role, makes the tagging of the individual task/block inside of the role *unnecessary* and hence **superfluous**).

Longer information:

Ansible, sadly invites often overly complicated and contorted syntax and style. In this very case it was only an unnecessary duplicate tagging, combined with an equally not necessary using of the syntactical element of a `block` (in ansible playbook).

How was the behaviour of ansible with regards to tagging verified/tested? => with a shell/bash sctipt:

I have resorted to this shell script that should test, how ansible `tags` behave in relationship  to this **implicit inheritance** with respect to roles.

the bash script will create an minimal ansible test case, which
contains two roles `role1` and `role2`, both being verbatim copies
with exception of the name (so to be able to tell them appart) and 
with 2 tasks:

- `task(A)` is **not** explicitly tagged
- `task(B)` is **explicitly** tagged with the tag 'tag01'.

A necessary ansible `playbook.yml` and host/inventory file `inventory.ini` is also 
created in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#make a temporary directory for test
TEMPDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
#change to temporary directory
cd "$TEMPDIR"

# create ansible hosts file "./inventory.ini" 
# only host we need is the the local box (to be simple disregard any ssh overhead)
cat > inventory.ini <<'EOF'
[hosts]
localhost ansible_connection=local
EOF

# create ansilble role "role1"
# (to keep it simple, we have minimal role with only a tasks entry)
mkdir -p roles/role1/tasks
# (the content for the tasks/main.yml file are two tasks, with one task
#  namely task(A) not being explicitly and the task(B) being explicitly
#  tagged)
cat > roles/role1/tasks/main.yml <<'EOF'
---
# tasks file for role1 and role2

- name: "task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'"
  debug:
    msg: "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" {{ role_name }} ."

- name: "task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'"
  debug:
    msg: "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" {{ role_name }} ."
  tags:
  - tag01
EOF


# create ansible role "role2" as a verbatim copy of "role1"
cp -r roles/role1 roles/role2

# now create an ansible playbook that uses these two ansible roles 
# (note that for the role "role1" we used "implicit tagging"
cat > playbook.yml <<'EOF'
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
  - role: "role1"
    tags: 
    - "tag01"
  - role: "role2"
EOF

# show the test setup 
find . 

# TEST 1:
# run "playbook.yml" one time "as is" ( i.e. no using of tags -> "all tasks"
# should be run)
echo "TEST1" | tee TEST1
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini playbook.yml | tee -a TEST1

# TEST 2:
# run "playbook.yml" with --tags command line options ( meaning this time
# we limit the task to be run to only those that have the specific tag)
echo "TEST2" | tee TEST2
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini --tags 'tag01' playbook.yml | tee -a TEST2

# TEST 3:
# run "playbook.yml" with --skip-tags command line options ( meaning this time
# we limit the task to be run all, but those to tags to be "skipped")
echo "TEST3" | tee TEST3
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini --skip-tags 'tag01' playbook.yml | tee -a TEST3

# show path of temporary directory 
echo "TEMPDIR is $TEMPDIR"
```

Having run this shell script it basically yields three results for

1. Test 1 "TEST1", `ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini playbook.yml`:  no tags usage => any implicit or explicit tagging is of no concurn all tasks for both roles `role1` and `role2` are run:

```
    TEST1

    PLAY [all] **************************************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost]

    TASK [role1 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
    }

    TASK [role1 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
    }

    TASK [role2 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
    }

    TASK [role2 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
    }

    PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
    localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

1. Test 2 "TEST2", `ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini --tags 'tag01' playbook.yml`:  tags are used => implicit and explicit tagging matters. Since 
   `tag01` is set for `role1` at level of the `role` both contained tasks task(A) and `task(B)` are run. Contrastingly for `role2` without the implictely inherited tagging only `task(B)` is run. The output shows that:

```
TEST2

    PLAY [all] **************************************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost]

    TASK [role1 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
    }

    TASK [role1 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
    }

    TASK [role2 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
    }

    PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
    localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

3. Lastly the Test 3 "TEST3" inverts all with `--skip-tags` where the implicit tagging for `role1` causes the whole role to be skipped. For `ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini --skip-tags 'tag01' playbook.yml` we have the following result:

```
TEST3

    PLAY [all] **************************************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost]

    TASK [role2 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
    }

    PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
    localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

In conclusion and to keep close with the topic of the question, the a tag for a task contained in a role, is superflous, if that very `role` is (a) already tagged itself in the `playbook` and hence makes all its task implicitly inherit the task and b) this is the only `playbook` the role is used anyway (as it was the case here).

Although the ouput can be generated via executing the shell script provided here its output as a courtesy and for being complete:

```
.
./playbook.yml
./roles
./roles/role2
./roles/role2/tasks
./roles/role2/tasks/main.yml
./roles/role1
./roles/role1/tasks
./roles/role1/tasks/main.yml
./inventory.ini
TEST1

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
}

TASK [role1 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
}

TASK [role2 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
}

TASK [role2 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

TEST2

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
}

TASK [role1 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role1 ."
}

TASK [role2 : task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(B) tagged explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

TEST3

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [role2 : task(A) tagged not explicitly 'tag01'] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "debug-msg: this is \"task(A) tag explicitly 'tag01'\" role2 ."
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

TEMPDIR is /tmp/tmp.cPE6a4gGiG
```